# Find Calulated Match on Existing Data Using Levensthein Method

Tags: sql, distance

I currently have a function that performs a Levensthein comparison between two values.  I am interested in using this type of function in two ways.

Option 1:
I would like to first go through an existing database field (Product Description) and compare all of the existing products against each other and return a calculated percent value that indicates the likelihood that a similar product already exists.  The results could look something like this:

```
[product1]   [percentmatch]   [product2]
'Large Cup'      66.66%        'Lg Cup'
```

I would assume that my select statement would then loop to the next product in the table and perform the same comparison to find a similar product.  Therefore, eventually I would see a duplicate result in the reverse order from what is listed above.

Option 2:
I would also like to use a script to search the database for similar products when I provide a variable to search for and have the same results be shown for any product that exceeds a 50% match for example.

```
[My New Variable]     [percentmatch]      [existingproductname]
X-Large Cup                81.81%              Large Cup
X-Large Cup                54.54%              Lg Cup
```

Thank you for your help with this in advance.  I look forward to seeing how I can do this.

Thanks,
D

Comment: What is the actual question? Also, please specify what flavor SQL you are interested in as our advice will probably be guided by that.

Comment: This reads like a requirements statement. "Here's what I need. Write the code for me. Be back later to pick it up. Tks bye." You've also failed to ask a question here (and if you had, you'd be asking two fairly complex ones in the same post, which isn't how things work here). What effort have you made to accomplish either of these goals?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to calculate percentage based on the number of edit operations vs. length of the 1st string:

```
100 * (1 - CAST(EDITDISTANCE(product1,product2) AS FLOAT) / CHAR_LENGTH(product1))
```

Option #1 will be a CROSS JOIN:

```
select product1
   ,100 * (1 - CAST(EDITDISTANCE(product1,product2) AS FLOAT) / CHAR_LENGTH(product1)) as percentmatch
   ,product2
from tab as t1
cross join t2
where product1 < product2  -- don't compare product with itself and don't compare two products twice
order by percent match desc
```

Option #2:

```
select 'X-Large Cup'
   ,100 * (1 - CAST(EDITDISTANCE('X-Large Cup',product) AS FLOAT) / CHAR_LENGTH('X-Large Cup')) as percentmatch
   ,product
from tab
order by percent match desc
```